# Google group doesn't appear in chrome developer's dashboard

Tags: chrome-web-store, google-groups

I want to publish chrome extension from Google group. [Here's](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#set-up-group-publishing) the official article.

> Create a new Google group and link to this new group: 1. Click Create
>   new group. You'll see the Google Groups page in a new tab. 2. Create
>   your new group. 3. Reload the Chrome Web Store dashboard page in your
>   browser, then follow the steps below under "Link to an existing Google
>   Group."

So here's my steps:

1. Create a new group from my gmail account (deathangel908). It's available [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!myforums)
2. Go to [developer's dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard?authuser=0), select my account on top. ***A**
3. But group doesn't appear in group list. ***B**

**A**:
[image]

**B**:

[image]

What do I do to make my group appear there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requiermnets:

- You can only have one publishing group associated with your account.
- You need to have a developer's account (5$ worth)

Steps:

- [Create a google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!myforums)
- In the [developer's dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard) you should inspect `Chose existing group` right at the bottom of the page. You can link your group to your curren account there.
- Afterwards you should see smth like this:
  [image]