# How to have both a user and developer group for a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension. I'm the developer, and I have a Google group for users than can use the extension. I want to add a collaborator to help develop it. From what I've seen on the Google Developer site, I'm apparently supposed to make a google group to add additional developers. But I see no option to create a new group on my Developer Dashboard.

I'm not sure why, but I have a guess: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598029/google-group-doesnt-appear-in-chrome-developers-dashboard) SO response, you can only have one publishing group associated with your account. So my user group may be preventing me from creating a developer group. But I need a user group — the extension is in testing, and I only want these approved users to be able to use it.

So what do I do? Do I have to create a new Google and developer account and simply give my collaborator the username and password? Or is there a way to do this without creating a new account (as I think that would mean my existing users would have to delete the old extension and re-add the new one, which could get messy as many of them aren't tech-savvy).

Comment: Try asking on [google's extensions group](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-extensions), there are official representatives who should be able to help.

Comment: Ahhh good point, trying that, thanks.